# How to combine a done callback with injection angular 2 unittest

Tags: angular, asynchronous, jasmine

I like the ability to pass in a done-callback when making unittest to explicitly control when a unittest is considered done. Can anyone explain how this can be combined with dependency injection when using Angular 2?

**A little more background:**

A normal unittest with a callback function looks like this:

```
it('should work with done', (done: Function) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      a.test();
    }, 1000);
    a.test = () => {
      console.log('zweiter test');
      expect(true).toBeFalsy();
      done();
    };
```

A unittest generated by the angular 2 framework uses injection and looks like this:

```
  it('should be defined', inject([TxparserService], (service: TxparserService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

I want to use both a callback function and dependency injection. How does that look?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if you can. Personally though, I stopped using this style of injection for a couple reasons: 1. It's pretty verbose, and 2. You need to keep repeating it for each test case. A couple other options are to:

- Use a `beforeEach`

  ```
  let service: TxparserService;

  beforeEach(() => {  // configure });

  beforeEach(inject([TxperserverService], (svc: TxparserService) => {
    service = svc;
  }));
  ```
- For me, the `beforeEach` above, still breaks my first concern of being verbose, so I just do it this way now

  ```
  let service: TxparserService;

  beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          providers: [ TxparserService ]
      });

      service = TestBed.get(TxparserService);
  });
  ```

Comment: Thx for the answer. That can work for me so I'll mark it as the answer for now.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to combine `done`-style async test with injection you can simply do the following:

```ts
it('should work', (done) => inject([SomeService], (someService: SomeService) =>
{
  expect(true).toEqual(true);
  done();
})());
```

Make sure that you immediately call the function returned by `inject`.

PS: Sometimes neither `async` nor `fakeAsync` works and you still need it to be `done` in old-school fashion...

PPS: If someone is interested how to overcome problems with time-dependent operations of Observable with [jasmine-marbles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-marbles) take a look at this short example: [marble-scheduler-injector.ts](https://gist.github.com/pavel-agarkov/9e7badefd14b725ca7867a25774d7a0e)

Comment: This may be related to: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10127

Comment: @vivri exactly, but lately I switched to [jasmine-marbles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-marbles) and now I don't need any type of async at all (at least for Observables) - it just works completely sync! PS: in order it to work you have to inject TestScheduler from jasmine-marbles into time-dependent Observable operations.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to successfully combine fakeAsync with inject. So it would look like following:

```
it('should be defined', fakeAsync(inject([TxparserService], (service: TxparserService) => {
  expect(service).toBeTruthy();
})));
```

You can combine it then with the `tick()` function described in https://angular.io/guide/testing#the-fakeasync-function

Comment: Worked for me the same way using 'async'.